# Firestore data can't display on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

[The app quit when I change the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjvnY.png) I am facing a problem when I try to develop an Android App that display the data from Firestore.

[image: Firestore database structure].

Can I know why it is not displaying the data on my RecyclerView and EventPage? I have rechecked everything, but I still can't find out why data doesn't show on EventPage.

EventPage.java

```
public class EventPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "DashboardFragment";
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<EventModel, EventViewHolder> adapter;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_page);
        
        //Set recyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerEventCard);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference cRef = db.collection("event");
        Query query = db.collection("event").orderBy("ASC").limit(10);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<EventModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<EventModel>()
                .setQuery(query, EventModel.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<EventModel, EventViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull EventModel model) {
                holder.textViewEName.setText(model.getEName());
                holder.textViewEDate.setText(model.getEDate());
                holder.textViewEVenue.setText(model.getEVenue());
                holder.textViewEDesc.setText(model.getEDesc());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                //Changes on XML file. Try it.
                View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_card_list, parent, false);
                return new EventViewHolder(v);
            }


        };

        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

EventModel.java

```
package com.example.myvolunteer;

public class EventModel {
    private String EName;
    private String EDate;
    private String EVenue;
    private String EDesc;

    //Constructor
    public EventModel(){}

    public EventModel(String EName, String EDate, String EVenue, String EDesc){
        this.EName = EName;
        this.EDate = EDate;
        this.EVenue = EVenue;
        this.EDesc = EDesc;
    }

    public String getEName() {
        return EName;
    }

    public void setEName(String EName) {
        this.EName = EName;
    }

    public String getEDate() {
        return EDate;
    }

    public void setEDate(String EDate) {
        this.EDate = EDate;
    }

    public String getEVenue() {
        return EVenue;
    }

    public void setEVenue(String EVenue) {
        this.EVenue = EVenue;
    }

    public String getEDesc() {
        return EDesc;
    }

    public void setEDesc(String EDesc) {
        this.EDesc = EDesc;
    }














}
```

EventViewHolder.java

```
package com.example.myvolunteer;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView textViewEName, textViewEVenue, textViewEDate, textViewEDesc;
    public EventViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewEName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEventName);
        textViewEDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEventDate);
        textViewEVenue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEventVenue);
        textViewEDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEventDesc);
    }

}
```

activity_event_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EventPage">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerEventCard"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="663dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

event_card_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#B7F1FE"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="432dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEventName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Event Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEventDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEventVenue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Venue"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEventDesc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/createText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="Created By: "
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textEventCreatedBy"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Leader Name"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/createText"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:backgroundTint="#adcae6"
                        android:text="More Info"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:textColor="@color/black">

                    </Button>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**make Sure your model class String variables are equal to your firestore data feild because it is very important to retrieve data from firestore**

```
    private String eventName;
    private String eventDate;
    private String eventVenue;
    private String eventDescription;

    //Constructor
    public EventModel(){}

    public EventModel(String eventName, String eventDate, String eventVenue, String eventDescription){
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
        this.eventVenue = eventVenue;
        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
    }

    public String geteventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void seteventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String geteventDate() {
        return eventDate;
    }

    public void seteventDate(String eventDate) {
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
    }

    public String geteventVenue() {
        return eventVenue;
    }

    public void seteventVenue(String eventVenue) {
        this.eventVenue = eventVenue;
    }

    public String geteventDescription() {
        return eventDescription;
    }

    public void seteventDescription(String eventDescription) {
        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
Query query = db.collection("event").orderBy("ASC").limit(10);
```

You are telling Firestore to sort by a field called `ASC`, which doesn't exist in your screenshot, so no documents are returned.

You probably want to sort on the ascending date, which you can do with:

```
Query query = db.collection("event").orderBy("eventDate", Direction.ASCENDING).limit(10);
```

---

Note that while the above will fix the problem of the documents *not* showing, they will still show up in the wrong order. This is because your `eventDate` field is not useful for sorting dates.

Strings in Firestore are sorted lexicographically, and in that order, "12/7/2021" becomes before "13/6/2021".

If you want to fix this problem, you can either store the dates as Firestore's built-in `Timestamp` type, or use a string format that allows sorting, like `"2021-07-12" (which is *after*` "2021-07-13"`.

Comment: When I change the line to `Query query = db.collection("event").orderBy("eventDate", "asc").limit(10);` , the app quit immediately when I try to go to EventPage.

Comment: That sounds like you may be hitting a different problem. I recommend checking your logcat output for what is going wrong now.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjvnY.png The logcat output is already included in this link.

Comment: I also have tried to search for the error I get from logcat, but I didn't found any that is worked to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, I checked the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#java_2) and the correct parameter for the order is `Direction.DESCENDING`. I highly recommend keeping the documentation handy for situations like this.

Comment: Thank you, I change it to this line `Query query = db.collection("event").orderBy("eventDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);`, but the data still not showing up.

Comment: Is there any bug that I haven't notice yet? The Cardview is shown, but I couldn't see any data...

Comment: Given the amount of code you shared there could be many more problems, but the fact that you tried to sort on a non-existing field `ASC` for sure would cause no data to be loaded, as no documents have that field.